# How to use razor syntax in asp.net mvc 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am developing an app in asp.net mvc 2.0 in which I want to implement Bread Crumb pattern. I browsed a lot of sites for this purpose and find the solution of my problem in MVC 3.0 through mvcsitemap provider. They are using razor syntax and I am unable to use the razor syntax in MVC 2.0. Please help me.

Comment: I think you already answered your own question. You must use MVC 3 if you want to use the Razor View Engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using Razor View Engine, you can covert your MVC 2 application to MVC 3.
It will not be possible to use Razor in MVC 2.

**MVC 3 Project Upgrade Tool**

[MVC 3 Project Upgrade Tool](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/59008)

This standalone application upgrades ASP.NET MVC 2 applications to ASP.NET MVC 3. It works for both ASP.NET MVC 3 RC 2 and RTM. The tool only supports Visual Studio 2010 solutions and MVC 2 projects targeting .NET 4.

It will not work with VS 2008 solutions, MVC 1 projects, or projects targeting .NET 3.5. Those projects will first have to be upgraded using Visual Studio 2010 and/or retargeted for .NET 4.